# Выровнять пункты меню по центру

Tags: html, css

Как можно выровнять пункты меню, чтобы они по вертикали располагались по центру ячейки?
http://jsfiddle.net/25dQT/2/

```css
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.nav {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 687px;
  height: 75px;
}
.nav ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 687px;
  height: 75px;
}
.nav ul li {
  float: left;
  background: url(../images/bg_menu_item.png) left 5px no-repeat;
  height: 57px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 38px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav ul li:first-child {
  background: none;
}
.nav ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 16px;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #830000;
}
.nav ul li a.active {
  color: #830000;
}
/*------------------------ teaser -----------------------*/

.teaser {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 277px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2px;
}
.teaser > img {
  width: 504px;
  height: 274px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Монтаж<br />отопления</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Монтаж<br />водоснабжения</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Портфолио</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Контакты</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`vertical-align: middle` не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пожалуйста http://jsfiddle.net/25dQT/4/

```css
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 687px;
  height: 75px;
}
.nav ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 687px;
  height: 75px;
  display: table;
}
.nav ul li {
  background: url(../images/bg_menu_item.png) left 5px no-repeat;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 57px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav ul li:first-child {
  background: none;
}
.nav ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 16px;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #830000;
}
.nav ul li a.active {
  color: #830000;
}
/*------------------------ teaser -----------------------*/

.teaser {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 277px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2px;
}
.teaser > img {
  width: 504px;
  height: 274px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Монтаж<br />отопления</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Монтаж<br />водоснабжения</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Портфолио</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Контакты</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, работает!